# Цифровая клавиатуру на ввод цифр

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, мобильная-разработка

Создаю формочку для мобильного приложения на HTML. Несколько полей цифровые. Как задать для них цифровую клавиатуру?

Если тип Number, то такая клавиатура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужна такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<input type="number">` не продходит вам?

Comment: как-то не совсем так работает

Comment: ну вы либо укажите, как вы хотите, чтобы оно работало, либо вопрос останется без ответа.

Comment: подредактировал вопрос...

Comment: мне кажется, вам нужна клавиатура не для ввода данных в инпут, а для совершения звонка. для этого служит `<input type="tel">`

Answer (score 2):

Тоже нужна была своя клавиатура.
Писал для своих нужд, может и вам подойдет.
 Для предпросмотра снизу нажмите на → `Выполнить код`,  потом →
`На всю страницу`

```js
var Q;
Q = {};
Q.timeInterval;
Q.flag = 0;

function timeIntervaStart() {
 if (Q.flag === 0) {
  Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
   Clear();
   timeIntervaStart();
   Q.flag = 1;
  }, 300);
 } else if (Q.flag === 1) {
  Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
   Clear();
   Q.flag = 2;
   timeIntervaStart();
  }, 150);
 } else {
  Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
   Clear();
   timeIntervaStart();
  }, 50);
 }
}

window.onmousedown = function() {
 var elem = window.event.srcElement;
 if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
  if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
   timeIntervaStart();
  }
 }
};

window.onmouseup = function() {
 var elem = window.event.srcElement;
 if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
  if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
   clearTimeout(Q.timeInterval);
            Q.flag = 0;
  }
 }
};

window.onclick = function() {
 var elem = window.event.srcElement;
 if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
  if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
   Clear();
  } else {
   document.getElementById('input_data').value += elem.innerHTML;
  }
 }
};

function Clear() {
 var str = document.getElementById('input_data').value;
 document.getElementById('input_data').value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;outline: 0;font-family: Consolas;}
#klava {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #edeef0;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#klava button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#klava .back-sp {
 background-color: #4286f5;
 color: #fff;
}
#input_data {
 background-color: #ffffeb;
 border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#klava button, #input_data {
 font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#klava button:active {
  background-color: #FFB74D;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_data" type="text" onfocus="this.blur();">

<div id="klava">
<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br>
<button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br>
<button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br>
<button>00</button><button>0</button><button class="back-sp">←</button><br>
</div>
```